# названия концертов по музыкальным инструментам

Tags: одним-словом

Правильно ли называть выступление арфиста, скрипача или пианиста "арфовым", "скрипковым" и "пианинным" концертом? Правильно ли вообще говорить "арфовый концерт" или "пианинный концерт" применительно к чему бы то ни было?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Скрипичный концерт", "фортепианный концерт" и т.д., это концерт не в смысле "выступление", а в смысле ["произведение"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29):

> Конце́рт — музыкальное произведение, чаще всего для одного или нескольких солирующих инструментов с оркестром. Существуют также концерты для одного инструмента — без оркестра, концерты для оркестра — без строго определённых сольных партий, концерты для голоса (или голосов) с оркестром и концерты для хора а cappella.

Другой вариант названия произведения - "концерт для (инструмента) с оркестром", например "концерт для фортепиано с оркестром", "концерт для арфы с оркестром". Кстати гугл находит "Гендель. Арфовый концерт" и "Арфовый концерт Бориса Тищенко", так что словосочетание "арфовый концерт" вполне употребляется.

Концерт в смысле "выступление пианиста/арфиста/скрипача" обычно употребляется в другой форме: "концерт фортепианной музыки", "концерт скрипичной музыки", "концерт арфовой музыки".

Пианино, на самом деле, одна из разновидностей фортепиано (в переводе с итальянского пианино - "маленькое фортепиано"). На концертах обычно используют другую разновидность фортепиано - рояль. Конструктивно пианино отличается от рояля расположением струн (у рояля струны расположены горизонтально, у пианино - вертикально). На концертах обычно используют рояль (википедия называет его "основным видом фортепиано") так как благодаря его конструкции он  имеет множество музыкальных преимуществ перед пианино (кроме компактности). Но ни "рояльной", ни "пианинной" музыки не существует - есть только "фортепианная".

Comment: Из собственного опыта могу сказать, что словосочетания вроде "арфовый концерт" — некий род музыкантского сленга, скорее. То есть ничто не мешает их употреблять, но, например, в официальной литературе, при объявлении со сцены будет "концерт для арфы". То же и с роялем. Пианисты часто говорят "играть на рояле" в смысле "играть на фортепиано" вообще. Словосочетание же "играть на пианино" воспринимается скорее как обучение, оно применимо к школьнику, например.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно говорят не пианинный, а "фортепианный", и это довольно приемлено.
"Скрипковый" не является общепринятым прилагательным, более подходящий вариант "скрипичный". Например, "скрипичный ключ" нотного стана.

Классически концерты называются относительно существительных с предлогом "для":

"Концерт для скрипки/арфы/фортепиано с оркестром".

Пианино в данном контексте не используется, так как является частным случаем фортепиано/клавира.

Answer (score 0):

никогда не слышал чтобы выступление пианиста называли фортепианным концертом. термин такой есть но он относится к произведению, а не выступлению. говорят "состоялся сольный концерт пианиста И. Иванова", если пианист известный то могут и без пианино: "состоялся сольный концерт Кисина", и так понятно что пианист